# Form do WPF está indo para trás de todas as janelas quando um ComboBox é selecionado

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Meu form `WPF` funciona perfeitamente, mas em um `ComboBox` específico, depois da ação de selecionar, o form está indo para trás de todas as janelas, sem maiores explicações, e isso não acontece em mais nenhum outro form, alguém saberia me explicar o porquê?

A imagem antes de clicar no `ComboBox`:

[image: A imagem antes de clicar no <code>ComboBox</code>]

O meu `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Name="CbAnimalSpecie" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="25" Width="130" Margin="100,0,250,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AnimalSpecies}" SelectedItem="{Binding Animal.AnimalSpecie}" SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecieCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Conforme pedido, segue minha `View` de processamento:

```
protected Helper.Views.ProcessingView ShowProcessing(Window ownerView)
{
    try
    {
        var processingView = new Helper.Views.ProcessingView();

        processingView.Owner = ownerView;
        processingView.Show();

        ownerView.IsEnabled = false;

        return processingView;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

protected void CloseProcessing(Window ownerView, Window processingView)
{
    try
    {
        ownerView.IsEnabled = true;

        processingView.Hide();
        processingView.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Meu `Command`:

```
public ICommand GetAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecieCommand
{
    get { return _getAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecieCommand ?? (_getAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecieCommand = new DelegateCommand(GetAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecie)); }
}
```

E, por fim, meu método:

```
private void GetAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecie()
{
    try
    {
        var processingView = base.ShowProcessing(this.AnimalUpdateView);

        this.AnimalBreedsOriginal = new Repository.AnimalBreed().GetAllAnimalBreeds();
        this.AnimalBreeds = new Repository.AnimalBreed().GetAllAnimalBreeds(T => T.AnimalSpecieId == this.Animal.AnimalSpecie.Id);

        base.CloseProcessing(this.AnimalUpdateView, processingView);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO 2**

Ok, achei parte do problema do Form, é esse trecho de código:

```
private void GetAllAnimalBreedsByAnimalSpecie()
{
    try
    {
        var processingView = base.ShowProcessing(this.AnimalUpdateView);
        .
        .
        .

        base.CloseProcessing(this.AnimalUpdateView, processingView);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Mas como disse, anteriormente, esse trecho funciona perfeitamente em todo o software, porque nesse momento ele tem esse comportamento estranho?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bom, achei a parte do código que estava dando problema:

```
var processingView = new Helper.Views.ProcessingView();
processingView.Owner = null;
processingView.Show();
ownerView.IsEnabled = false;
return processingView;
```

Por algum motivo estranho, no único momento, descrito na pergunta acima, o form ia para trás de tudo se estivesse com a propriedade `processingView.Owner` preenchida, agora, com ela anulada, funciona perfeitamente...